# Backgroundworker allowing UI to freeze when iterating through Outlook MailItems

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook, backgroundworker, mailitem

I'm working on a WPF support tool that looks at a shared Outlook Mailbox, collects the Folders, creates TabItems in a TabControl to represent the folders, then collects MailItems that it finds in the Folders of the past 14 days.  Each Folder probably only has about a dozen MailItems, so not a large amount by any stretch.

On startup the application iterates through each of the Folders' Mailitems and adds them to a MailItem List that I will later add to the bound ObservableCollection of the respective TabItem's ListBox.

The problem I have is that the UI locks as it iterates through the MailItems in the Outlook folders.  I added a Backgroundworker routine to collect the mail in the background first, but the UI is still completely unresponsive during this time.  I don't understand why as this process is not messing with the UI at all.

My simplified code below.  Notice that I am actually doing nothing with the MailItems other than iterating through them in this example but it freezes the UI.  Why?  Also of note is that there are about 10 Outlook folders total.  A TabItem (with a ListBox as content) is created to represent a folder and would thus cause the below code to fire up -- in  other words there should be about 10 Backgroundworkers starting up during the initialization process.

Any suggestions or ideas to better implement this?  Ideally I want the app to start up and smoothly populate the display, not hang and suddenly display everything.

```
List<MailItem> mailList = new List<MailItem>();

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(delegate
            {
                Items folderItems = folder.Items.Restrict(filter);

                foreach (MailItem mi in folderItems.OfType<MailItem>())
                {
                    // would normally add to mailList here. 
                }
            });
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(delegate
            {
                 // then add to the ObservableCollection of the UI ListBox.
            });

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        worker.Dispose();
```

Comment: If you are already using Backgorundworker try to use .WhenAny or IProgress to update your windows asynchronously. The keyword here is [TAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) (Task-based Asynchronous Pattern). Also beware of creationg refernces in your foreach mi loop

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is causing your UI lockup, but you shouldn't be calling `Dispose` on a `BackgroundWorker` right after `RunWorkerAsync` as that will run at roughly the same time as `DoWork` and before `RunWorkerCompleted`. You can call `Dispose` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler (I prefer this because it keeps everything in one place) or save the worker and do it sometime later when the containing class is disposed.